# How do I exclude a specific controller action from needing authentication?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, identityserver3

**Background**

I'm adding self-checks to an API, secured by OAuth2, using Identity Server 3. I've added a `MonitoringController` for this, with a limited set of checks.

The main check I want to do is make sure it's possible to request a token, using fixed test credentials.

Our monitoring system can than do regular calls to this action and make sure it's possible to request a token, which is a stronger check than just a keep-alive ping (which we also have).

**However**

As the entirety of the API is under authentication, the `MonitoringController` is as well, by default.

This means my token request check isn't allowed. Having to request a token first defeats the whole purpose of this check.

> How can I exclude my MonitoringController from needing authentication,
>   while making sure all other controllers are still checked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to put the `AllowAnonymous` attribute on the controller or method.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DoSomeMonitoring()
```